Ensuring .NET Metrics Appear at Prometheus /metrics Endpoint
When using the Prometheus Exporter for OpenTelemetry metrics in .NET 8, the /metrics HTTP GET endpoint only displays metrics that have been recorded (i.e., written to at least once) and whose associated Meter instance has been instantiated by Dependency Injection (i.e., the service with the Meter has to have been instantiated in the app).
This poses a challenge when building dashboards for metrics that are infrequently recorded, such as exception counters or metrics tied to abnormal execution paths—they simply don't appear at the /metrics endpoint until they're used.
Partial Solution:
For Counter<T> and UpDownCounter<T>, I've found a partial solution that involves invoking .Add(0) or .Add(0, tags) when creating the metric. This registers it without skewing the data, allowing it to appear at the /metrics endpoint.
However, this approach doesn't work for Histogram metrics. Calling .Record(0) upon creation records a zero value, which I understand will skew the data by populating the lowest bucket of the histogram.
Questions:

Is there a way to easily get all the registered metrics for the Meter?
How can I initialize a Histogram<T> metric so that it appears at the /metrics endpoint without recording actual data and affecting the histogram's distribution? Or if we do a .Record(0) is there a way to reset the data?
For Counter<T> and UpDownCounter<T>, does the .Add(0) hack have any adverse effects?


What values would you expect to get from metrics that haven't published anything yet? And why is a missing empty metric a problem for the dashboard? If a metric value doesn't exist yet, the dashboard shouldn't display a value. Missing values and gaps are expected in time series, especially for distributed systems.

0 isn't the same as an UNKnown value in this case. A service exception count of 0 means a service is running fine when in fact, it may not be running at all.

I appreciate the distinction between 0 and unknown.
From what I understand, the .NET Prometheus exporter replaces "." with "_".
So, in my app I may name a metric "exceptions.counter" and, had I not known about the "." replacement functionality, in the dashboard I'd try setup a graphic for "exceptions.counter" and I would never get data.
Had I just known that the metric was registered as "exceptions_counter" I would confidently be able to setup a dashboard knowing that I'm using the correct metric names.
